# In Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy, how much did six pints cost?

Tags: the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy

Ford orders six pints of beer (muscle relaxant) and pays with a five pound note.  When he is told to keep the change, the barman is genuinely thankful for such a large tip.

How much did a pint of beer cost back then?

Comment: I've always been bemused at how few people have noticed, or commented upon, the many protoThatcher ideas expressed in the original radio series - the Union of Seers & Thinkers, the nasty council employee who wiped a couple of Arthur's windows and charged a fiver, the way the foreman was able to order a bulldozer to run over a citizen.
As with the price of beer, the same with the packets of peanuts.

Comment: @ladysynthia - I wouldn't call those things "Pro-Thatcher". They're simply caricatures of Britain in the late 1970s

Comment: VALORUM - That was PROTO thatcher, not PRO. Bear in mind that the radio series was written during the soi-disant Winter of Discontent (a creation of murdoch myrmidons & Saatchi & Saatchi)of the kate 70s when union bashing was all the rage.

Answer (score 65):

The joke was [written in 1978](http://www.clivebanks.co.uk/THHGTTG/THHGTTGradio1.htm) when the average cost of a pint of beer (according to the [Office of National Statistics' Average Price Index](https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=/economy/inflationandpriceindices/methodologies/consumerpricesindexcpiandretailpricesindexrpibasketofgoodsandservices/rpiaverageprices19142004tcm77168515tcm77420253.xls)) was  around 40p. This means that Ford was tipping the barman approximately £2.60 or roughly 110% of the purchase price.

Despite a slight rise in the price of a pint by the time of the 1981 TV Series (something around 53p according to the [Daily Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/personalfinance/8414458/1981-What-was-the-price-of-a-pint-and-who-was-top-of-the-pops.html?image=2) and the ONS), this still represented a tip of £1.80 and would have been seen as very generous as a tip for a member of the serving staff.

---

As an aside, you'll note that for the [2005 film](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Hitchhiker's-Guide-to-the-Galaxy,-The.html) they dramatically upped the ante, presumably to stop rising prices from instantly making the film look outdated.

> **BARMAN:** *There you are, six pints.*
>
> Ford slaps down a £50 note. The barman's impressed.
>
> **FORD:** *Keep the change. You've got ten minutes to spend it.*

Comment: That doesn't seem an overly generous tip, though.  Do the English not tip?

Comment: The English do not, generally, tip at all, except in resturants and even then it's not guaranteed. To a barman in an English pub, they'd look at you funny...especially when HHGTTG was written.

Comment: @DanEckhart I would say that in any part of the world a 67% tip is a pretty generous amount.

Comment: These comments have been straying a little off-topic, so I [copied them to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40032/discussion-on-answer-by-valorum-in-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy-how-much-di), where you can continue to discuss tipping customs for as long as you like. (With apologies to @Valorum :-) )

Comment: The tipping discussion might be better off at https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tipping btw - or simply read about at [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratuity)

Comment: Just to add further context, £5 in 1978 would be worth around £30 today. http://www.thisismoney.co.uk/money/bills/article-1633409/Historic-inflation-calculator-value-money-changed-1900.html

Comment: Meh, in some places you'd be lucky to get six pints for £50 lol

Comment: I am sooooo sorry for upvoting the answer, solely because now it has 43 upvotes instead of the appropriate **42**.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Someone's been to London, I see :-)

Comment: @Valorum: I try to stay away as much as possible, but I have friends who live there.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I have long since learned that the secret to happy travels into the London area is packed lunches and a hip-flask.

Comment: @Valorum: The secret to happy travels into the London area is "don't" ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit even today in 2022, the average price of a pint in London is less than £6. Leaving £14 as a tip, around 40%.

Comment: Traditionally bar staff in England were "tipped" but generally not like that. "Have one for yourself" or words to that effect would entitle them to a tip of the price of a pint or some similar sum which they would deduct. So the custom is not unknown.